# Reference request: Functional equations for math competitions

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for some articles and resources to study functional equations to prepare for a math contest. I found some books on the internet but none of them have been written for math contests, but their readers are mainly intended to be graduate students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at Functional Equations and How to Solve Them, by Christopher Small.

There are also several sets of notes written up, if you do a hunt on Google.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose I used chapter 11 of book [Engel, A. Problem-Solving Strategies](http://books.google.cz/books?id=wj3_FxnRz5kC).

Comment: You can download chapter 11 [here](https://pdfzen.com/8faaff).

Comment: Thank you mcihak and @GitGud for your help.